# Laravel Passport returned all users

Tags: laravel

I created a user auth system based on Passport in my app and now I have some troubles. When I send a token, my details() method returned all app users instead of specific one. I paste my code to show exactly what is going on.

Login method:

```
public function login(){ 
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('myapp')->accessToken; 
            $user->api_token = $success['token'];
            $user->save();
            return response()->json(['user' => $success], $this->successStatus); 
        } 
        else{ 
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
        } 
    }
```

It return something like that:

```
{
    "user": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImFjMzEwM2UyMzIwNGIxMjg3M2E3ZWMyZmUyNGJkNDEzMTQyN2I1ZWUzMWRjOGFhZjRhMzcyMDQzM2ZmNGJiZGJjZGU3ZjQ1ZjZkNzZmMGRkIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYWMzMTAzZTIzMjA0YjEyODczYTdlYzJmZTI0YmQ0MTMxNDI3YjVlZTMxZGM4YWFmNGEzNzIwNDMzZmY0YmJkYmNkZTdmNDVmNmQ3NmYwZGQiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTIxMzIyODMsIm5iZiI6MTU1MjEzMjI4MywiZXhwIjoxNTgzNzU0NjgzLCJzdWIiOiIxOCIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.LmwTCSlRTrZ9pq01JK6tfsx5yjjA9qfidTws-0_vVc-UsFKQOJSk-K1uAYMR5gd0SQzC8VyG8bIJLVdPZbm5ggXkk-itN1bHEdZPFT7zdx7rOTFVF1ri9-chZIDL6nElosk3SOw_1QwuwOxiMHBB7ss9ItPHrtwkNEMxpeh16henknIZVYct0Vn1grztdnh7EJCM9SkKjIxqF0yozuw-wsN-UmsLvNoFZkOFWuNCPC9Mawx_ip2VBD26mwcxzTgD1XFwRloTCtDOAZfQ4DfgS_YuuXEPn8pfrkp92C1lxGXp09Wu0ZdzFaIf8LWEQXCgwlqvsVuFSnKt3lGyEPuHuJc_DjZZTcWgjslVQr7RhEqWQmRK2xlJpiAcZyWoI1vhfYLmullr1vf7nGCoRsp3UDZB64J2oPVjomcClEfseAKQbIq_9roKxIGjTeYdaF2vwHCosaxzrak7AqBHkze-z5cL8ix9G6rWBeg4sDUPhiLDgrgHK4ywxBqHMyto-Ywak56pzq1767r4reunDyNYDhLwSt0IiK1Hmx7ZQ9j6_EWy3NLf1oy7eGc33bj7eQNusbEa0TfcXujNK299RAEnTFLEc4kuS_otHzGrwSvOx2zYPsZkctZYn19YoyKaeP7hM1ek0zfIlGXsxQI84osPl91U7PHqAufIK6YJeizcik0"
    }
}
```

When I have my token for specific user I send that token to details().

Details method:

```
public function details(Request $request) 
    { 
        $userData = $request->user()->with('kids')->with('hobbies')->with('conversations')->get();

        return response()->json(['user' => $userData], $this->successStatus); 
    }
```

Here is my api.php route file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('details', 'UserController@details');
});
Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
Route::post('register', 'UserController@register');
```

I don't know why my details method return all app users. Do you have any advice how I can fix that? I really appreciate any help with that trouble.

Comment: On your details method what output does `Auth::user()->id` display could you try?

Comment: Hi, var_dump(Auth::user()->id) return int(18). I tried something like $userData = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->with('kids')->with('hobbies')->with('conversations')->get() but it still return all users

Comment: I change my query to $userData = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('kids')->with('hobbies')->with('conversations')->firstOrFail();  and it works fine.